# Enviar e-mail após o upload estar concluído?

Tags: javascript, email, nodemailer, hapijs, anexo

Tenho a seguinte função para envio de e-mails utilizando o nodemailer e um servidor HapiJS:

```
let data = request.payload;
    if (data.file) {
        let name = data.file.hapi.filename;
        let caminho = __dirname + "/uploads/" + name;
        let file = fs.createWriteStream(caminho);

        file.on('error', function (err) {
            console.error(err)
        });

        data.file.pipe(file);

        data.file.on('end', function (err) {
            mailOptios.attachments.push({
                filename: name,
                path: caminho //push nos anexos quando o upload está concluido
            });
            reply('Upload Concluído');
        });
    }


    let destinatario = 'email@hotmail.com';
    let ass = 'teste com anexo';
    let email = 'Teste com anexo';
    let mailOptios = {
        from: usuario, //usuário está definido mais acima no código
        to: destinatario, //não incluí usuário aqui por questões de privacidade
        subject: ass,
        text: email,
        attachments: [
        ]
    };

    console.log(mailOptios);
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptios, function (err, info) {
        if (err){
            console.log(err)
        } else {
            console.log('Enviado! ' + info.response);
            return reply.response('Enviou')
        }
    })
```

Porém, o processo está ocorrendo de forma assíncrona e o email está sendo enviado antes de ocorrer o upload completo do anexo.

Como deixar essa função síncrona ou garantir que o anexo esteja pronto antes de enviar o email?

Comment: Não podes jogar a função "transporter.sendMail(...);" depois de "reply('Upload Concluído');", simplesmente ?

Comment: Após pequenos teste e adaptações funcionou perfeitamente, por favor adicione uma resposta para que eu possa aceitá-la e possivelmente ajudar à outras pessoas que possam ter essa dúvida...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você tem que colocar todo esse código aqui:

```
let destinatario = 'email@hotmail.com';
let ass = 'teste com anexo';
let email = 'Teste com anexo';
let mailOptios = {
    from: usuario, //usuário está definido mais acima no código
    to: destinatario, //não incluí usuário aqui por questões de privacidade
    subject: ass,
    text: email,
    attachments: [
    ]
};

console.log(mailOptios);
transporter.sendMail(mailOptios, function (err, info) {
    if (err){
        console.log(err)
    } else {
        console.log('Enviado! ' + info.response);
        return reply.response('Enviou')
    }
})
```

Dentro do `data.file.on('end')`, isto porque o `on` é um evento, de forma que ele está enviando uma mensagem dizendo que o upload terminou. Eu aconselho você transformar isso tudo em uma função `sendMail` e mandar os parâmetros necessários dentro do evento `end`